# dat file is not get created by buffered writer

Tags: java, file

I am stuck up in a odd sitution I have to create a .dat file named abc.dat but the issue is that when I create it then in my c: drive I check that file with extension .dat is not cretaed instead file with extension type _auto_file
is created , please advise how can I correct my code so that .dat file extension get created...

```
if ( totaltsers.size()>0){
    try {// Generate a file
        //File file = new File(

        String finalfilename= abamfilepath+ getFileName();
        System.out.println(finalfilename);

        File file = new File(abamfilepath+ getFileName());
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = null;
        BufferedWriter bw = null;

        Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
        CharsetEncoder charsetEncoder = charset.newEncoder();
        charsetEncoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file.getPath());
        outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream, charsetEncoder);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);

        if (file.exists()){
            file.delete();
        }

        for (tser tser : totaltsers) {
            for (toabj bk : books) {
                //if (tser.toabjdfr() == null)
                if((tser.toabjdfr() == null) &&(tser.ghjk() == null )){
                    bw.write("aaa");
                }
                else if (tser.toabjdfr() == null && tser.ghjk() != null ){
                    bw.write("bb");     
                }
                else if ( tser.toabjdfr() != null && tser.ghjk() == null){
                    bw.write("ccc");    
                }
            else
                    bw.write("ddd");
                bw.newLine();
            }
        }     
        bw.flush();
        bw.close(); 
        fileOutputStream.close();
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        String message = "Ate exception : " + e.getMessage();
        System.err.println(message);
        logger.error(message);
    }
}
```

below are the to construct the file name

```
public String getFileName() {
    return buildFileName();
}

private String buildFileName() {
    String  filename  = "abc";
    filename = filename+".dat";
    return filename;
```

i have done the changes as suggested but still not working.. but it is still not working please advise

```
String finalfilename= abamfilepath+ getFileName();
         System.out.println(finalfilename);
            File file = new File(abamfilepath + getFileName());
             FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file.getPath());
              OutputStreamWriter    outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream);
               BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
               if (file.exists()) {
                file.delete();
            }


             file.createNewFile();




    }
```

Comment: What's the value of `abamfilepath`?

Comment: file created with extension `dat_auto_select or only auto_select` ??

Comment: abamfilepath is picked up from properties file the complete location in properties file is ..C:\\Applications\\

Comment: the type of file is created is _auto_file as seen in windows but I want .dat type of file to be get created and the size is also 0 bytes intresting thing is that if I hard code the file name then everythings works fine

Comment: Do a System.out.println(abamfilepath+ getFileName()); and check the actual path that is printed. I'm suspicious of the double backslashes. You can use forward slashes and java will convert it appropriately to the correct File.separator.

Answer (score 3):

First, use the file itself to create the FileInputStream, like this:

```
    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

then, after this line:

```
    if (file.exists()){
        file.delete();
    }
```

include the code

```
    file.createNewFile();
```

That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

A statement like File f = new File(file); will not create a file on disk. Class `java.io.File` only represents a file path, not the actual file on disk.

To create a new file, open a `FileOutputStream` for it, which you can then use to write data to the file.

Comment: +1 for the info provided :-), though I have to wait for 7 hours to upvote this, my limit is gone for the day :(